# configuración regional no admitida en produccion con digitalocean en django python

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, digitalocean

Estoy tratando de colocar un proyecto en producción de Python con Django como framework pero al intentar acceder me arroja este error...

[image: error]

Dentro del proyecto en mi función de home llamo a la función de calendar, para mostrar un calendario por mes, lo hago de esta manera.

```
today = datetime.date.today()
calendarHTML_ant = calendar.LocaleHTMLCalendar(calendar.MONDAY, 'es_ES')
tabla_ant = calendarHTML_ant.formatmonth(today.year, (today.month - 1))
```

He intentado cambiando las configuraciones de locales en el droplet (Ubuntu 20.04), pero aún asi, me sigue presentando el error, incluso con el comando **LC_ALL=C**, pero no funciono, agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Cómo installas django en digitalocean? Usas dockerfile?

Comment: Lo instalo con pip, desde el requirements.txt